# Meteor Search-Source Has vague instruction, not sure where this code goes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I am making an web app with meteor and I have already created a databse of a bunch of elements, now I need to be able to have them come up when a user searches for them. I found a package called search-source. It can be found here:

https://github.com/meteorhacks/search-source

or here:

https://meteorhacks.com/implementing-an-instant-search-solution-with-meteor

My problem is I cant figure out how to implement this into my meteor project. Their instructions are very vague and I am having trouble figuring out where to put the code they give, and what I need to change to make it search through my database. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far? Some code? Don't want to sound strange but the content from the 2nd link is self explanatory and easy to follow, no?

Comment: I am sorta new to javascript and server stuff so this sounds pretty foreign to me.  I understand javascript code completely, but directions for placement dont come so easily to me... i just need an explanation of where things go, and if I wanted to customize this to my own code, what aspects of it I would change